# Cannot delete Directory, doesn't exist?

Tags: ssh, directory, rm

Somehow this folder got created when i was logged in via sftp.

```
"Sep 19 18:50 "
```

I tried to delete it via sftp.

Tried to SSH in and delete with rm -rf as root

```
Error:  rm /home/user/Downloads/manual/Sep 19 18:50  : no such file or directory
```

If i ls -al it shows it there.

```
root@ndsdsd:/home/user/Downloads/manual# ls -al
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan  4096 Sep 19 18:50
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan 12288 Sep 20 07:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 keelan keelan 16384 Sep 19 23:11 ..
```

[image]

Comment: Note that @Mat's way requires that you be able to log in and run programs (usually this means, log in with `ssh` and get a shell prompt). You cannot run `echo Sep* | hexdump -C` via sftp itself.

Comment: root@ds3dfe:/home/user/Downloads/manual# echo Sep* | hexdump -C
00000000  53 65 70 2a 0a                                    |Sep*.|
00000005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root@dsadwsd:/home/user/Downloads/manual# ls -al
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan  4096 Sep 19 18:50
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan 12288 Sep 20 07:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 keelan keelan 16384 Sep 19 23:11 ..
```

When i highlighted:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan  4096 Sep 19 18:50
```

There was a space at the end. So i did:

```
root@dsadwsd:/home/user/Downloads/manual# rm -rf " "
```

This removed the folder. Strange how the folder name wouldn't just be blank (space) but instead took the folder creation date.

I can now replicate this by creating a new folder via sftp with a space as the name, it changes the folder name to the creation date.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you really have a file called `Sep 19 18:50`.

I made an new folder `tmp`, then made a single file `foo` in that folder. Then I `sftp`'d in, `cd`'d to `tmp`, and ran `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 ek       ek           4096 Sep 19 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x   30 ek       ek           4096 Sep 19 19:39 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 ek       ek              0 Sep 19 19:39 foo
```

You'll notice that all entries show a date and time. That's not part of their name, it's just the time they're marked as having last been modified.

The name is to the right of that, separated by a space. Thus there are three entries:

- `foo`, the file I created.
- `..`, which represents the *parent* directory (i.e., the folder one up):

  ```
  sftp> pwd
  Remote working directory: /home/ek/tmp
  sftp> cd ..
  sftp> pwd
  Remote working directory: /home/ek
  ```

  <sup>(Except when you're in `/`. There's nothing above `/` in the directory tree. Then--and only then--`..` represents the same directory as `.`.)</sup>
- `.`, which represents the *current* directory (i.e., the directory you're in now).

  ```
  sftp> cd tmp
  sftp> pwd
  Remote working directory: /home/ek/tmp
  sftp> cd .
  sftp> pwd
  Remote working directory: /home/ek/tmp
  ```

`ls` only shows the `.` and `..` entries when the `-a` flag is supplied (or when you explicitly give their names, or a pattern that matches them, after `ls` on the command line). This is true both of the `ls` command in `sftp` and the [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ls.1.html) command issued on a full login session with a regular shell prompt.

Comment: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/axXeOke.png) FTP shows it as a folder. Can't delete it via ftp.

Comment: @Keelan I wonder if that's a bug in your graphical sftp client. (Which GUI client is that?) It is odd, after all, that the file's reported name is the *exact* date and time, down to the minute, of its own timestamp. In any case, `drwxr-xr-x 8 keelan keelan 16384 Sep 19 18:50 ..` is *not* reporting a file named `Sep 19 18:50`, but instead one named `..`. Is that line the *full* output of `ls -al` in that directory, when run in the command-line sftp client? Do you have access to ssh in and get a shell? If so, that would provide more powerful mechanisms for checking the directory's contents.

Comment: Filezilla, I tried a different ftp client and the directory is called:" 18:50  " without the Sep. I have SSh access.
Full output:

drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan  4096 Sep 19 18:50
drwxrwxr-x 3 keelan keelan 12288 Sep 20 07:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 keelan keelan 16384 Sep 19 23:11 ..

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting the output of `ls`. The actual directory name is `..` and it is a special directory used to navigate through the file-system (like when you type `cd ..` to go one level up). Every sub-directory has one. `Sep 19 18:50` is just the creation date of the directory.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/axXeOke.png Is showing a folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to the spaces try this:

```
sudo rm -rf "/home/user/Downloads/manual/Sep 19 18:50"
```

Comment: I thought this too, this doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: what if you remove `sudo rm -rf /home/user/Downloads/manual/` then `sudo mkdir /home/user/Downloads/manual/`

Comment: Error: Directory /home/keelan/Downloads/manual/Sep 19 18:50  : no such file or directory
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: Wtf doesnt make sense

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's an empty folder. the `..` part actually means that you can go " up a step" in the file tree if you type `cd ..`

Comment: That is the problem i am trying to delete this empty folder however i cannot. It shows it in LS -al and shows it in FTP but i cannot remove it.